# How to speed up VBA to Extract data from Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am new to stackoverflow and a newbie to VBA coding. At my work, we are supplied with shipment data in the form of Ms Word which is not very useful. I have found a way to transfer the data using VBA and have a code that is fully functional. However, the data set contains hundreds of thousands of records. I tried running a month's worth of data with 200k records and it took 5 days. Just wondering if there is anything in my code that I could be improved to speed up the process. I've tried turning off screen updates, events, calculations but it didn't do much. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Sub Word_to_Excel()

Dim FName As String, FD As FileDialog
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim WDR, WDCheck, ShipmentID As Object
Dim ExR As Range
Dim file
Dim Path As String
Dim ImportDate As Object
Dim ImportValue As String
Dim ShipmentIDcheck As String
Dim objResult



    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Set ExR = Selection ' current location in Excel Sheet

    ' Select Folder containing word documents
    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    FD.Show
    FName = FD.SelectedItems(1)

    file = Dir(FName & "\*.docx")

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    ' Open word document in the folder, run macro, close it and open the next word document until there are none left
    Do While file <> ""
    wdApp.Documents.Open Filename:=FName & "\" & file
    wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = 1
    wdApp.Visible = True

    ' Once the word doc is open, go to beginning of document and search for CTY/SITE/SORT:
    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=6
    wdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    wdApp.Selection.Find.Execute "CTY/SITE/SORT:"
    Set WDCheck = wdApp.Selection

    ' If "CTY/SITE/SORT:" is found, then look for Shipment ID
    Do While WDCheck = "CTY/SITE/SORT:"

    ' Find first shipment
    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=11
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=11, Extend:=1
    Set ShipmentID = wdApp.Selection
    ShipmentIDcheck = Replace(ShipmentID, " ", "")

    ' Transfer information from Word to Excel for a Shipment ID and go to the next one.
    ' Shipment ID should be a string that is 11 characters long
    ' If Shipment ID no longer exist, go to next page by searching for the next CTY/SITE/SORT:
    Do While Len(Trim(ShipmentIDcheck)) = 11
        i = i + 1
        ExR(i, 1) = file
        ExR(i, 2) = ShipmentIDcheck

    ' Consignee Name
    wdApp.Selection.MoveUp Unit:=5, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=12
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 3) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer Name
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 8) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper Name
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 13) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Quantity
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=10, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 19) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Weight
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=12, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 20) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Value
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=12, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 21) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Broker
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=11, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 23) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Consignee Street
    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 4) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer Street
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 9) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper Street
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 14) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Description
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=8
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=40, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 18) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Consignee City
    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 5) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Consignee Province
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 6) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Consignee Postal
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=6, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 7) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer City
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 10) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer Province
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 11) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer Postal
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=6, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 12) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper City
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 15) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper Province
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 16) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper Postal
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=6, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 17) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Country of Origin
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=29
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=21, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 22) = Trim(WDR)

    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=11, Extend:=1
    Set ShipmentID = wdApp.Selection
    ' Remove spaces from selection. Selection is then used to check if it is a shipment ID.
    ' If it is, then data for that shipment ID is transferred. If not, macro will go to the next page in the Word Doc.
    ShipmentIDcheck = Replace(ShipmentID, " ", "")

    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

    Loop

    'Simulate keyboard press "NUMLOCK" to prevent screen from locking
    objResult = objShell.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}")

    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    wdApp.Selection.Find.Execute "CTY/SITE/SORT:"
    Set WDCheck = wdApp.Selection

    Loop

    wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    file = Dir()

    Loop

    wdApp.Quit

    MsgBox "Data extraction completed at:" & vbNewLine & Format(Now, "mmmm d, yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")

End Sub
```

This is how the dataset is formatted. There are multiple word documents containing pages and pages of this dataset per day. Number of shipments per page varies. But the format are the same throughout. There are no tables in the word documents, just text separated by spaces. CTY/SITE/SORT: is unique to every page and I used it as an anchor point. if the macro finds it, then it goes down 11 lines and takes the first shipment ID and the other information. It then checks for the next shipment ID. If it is not there, then it goes to the next page and repeats the process.

```
REPORT NUM   : ABC1234                                   OPERATIONS SYSTEM                                       PAGE NUM:   2      
 CTY/SITE/SORT: CA 00123                                    SUMMARY CARGO                                         RUN TIME: 07:33:43 
 SORT DATE    :                                            INBOUND - SCAN                                         RUN DATE: 01AUG19  
                                                                                                                  OPER ID : ABC123  
 MVMT: 12345678   MVMT DT: 01AUG19    MAWB:                  PROD TYP:      DTY TYP:      IMP CTY:      EXP CTY:      BL TYP:        
                        COURIER REMISSION  MANIFEST               EXPORT SITE: US 12345                                

 GCCN ID:               EXPECTED SHPTS:           EXPECTED PKGS:             EXPECTED WEIGHT:                                        

 CUSTOMS NUM     CONSIGNEE NAME           IMPORTER NAME           SHIPPER NAME        CSA    QTY     WGT(LBS)   VALUE  BROKER        
 SHIPMENT ID                                                                               DESCRIPTION           (CAD) CTRY OF ORIGIN
             JOHN SMITH              ABC COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1      1000.00 UNCONSIGNED
 ABC12345678 123 MAIN STREET         345 RANDOM ROAD         UNIVERSITY OF WASHINGTO       BICYCLE PARTS                             
             VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 VANCOUVER     BC V2B1B2 SEATTLE       WA 981234                            US                   
             JOHN SMITH              ABC COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1      1000.00 UNCONSIGNED
 ABC12345678 123 MAIN STREET         345 RANDOM ROAD         UNIVERSITY OF WASHINGTO       BICYCLE PARTS                             
             VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 VANCOUVER     BC V2B1B2 SEATTLE       WA 981234                            US                   
             JOHN SMITH              ABC COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1      1000.00 UNCONSIGNED
 ABC12345678 123 MAIN STREET         345 RANDOM ROAD         UNIVERSITY OF WASHINGTO       BICYCLE PARTS                             
             VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 VANCOUVER     BC V2B1B2 SEATTLE       WA 981234                            US                   
             JOHN SMITH              ABC COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1      1000.00 UNCONSIGNED
 ABC12345678 123 MAIN STREET         345 RANDOM ROAD         UNIVERSITY OF WASHINGTO       BICYCLE PARTS                             
             VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 VANCOUVER     BC V2B1B2 SEATTLE       WA 981234                            US                   
       TOTAL FOR DUTY TYPE COURIER REMISSION                                                                                         
       TOTAL SHIPMENTS:                      4                                                                                       
       TOTAL PACKAGES :                      4                                                                                       
       TOTAL WEIGHT   :                     70.9 LBS                                                                                 
       TOTAL VALUES   :                   4000.00                                                                                         
* * *
```

I used the following code to cleanup the dataset and arrange them to one record per line and each line is separated by a paragraph (thank you, macropod). As the data is arranged into columns separated by spaces, I can then save it as a .txt file and import it into excel. The challenge now is to apply the code to all the docs in a folder and generate a .txt file for each one. Or it would be even better if the code can combine all the data from the cleaned .docx files into one .txt file.

```
Sub CleanWordDoc()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim p As Long, StrOut As String

With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "REPORT NUM   : * CTRY OF ORIGIN^13" 'Clean header on each page
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[ ]{2,}ACTUAL SHP TOTAL*[ ]{20,}^13^m" 'Clean footer on some pages
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[ ]{2,}TOTAL FOR DUTY*[ ]{20,}^13^m" 'Clean more footers
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "REPORT NUM   :*SUMMARY*[\*] [\*][ ]{20,}^13" 'Clean last page
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "^m^13" ' Clean all page breaks
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "^13^13" ' Clean empty paragraphs
    .Replacement.Text = "^13"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "<[ ]{1,}^13" ' Clean spaces and paragraphs at the beginning of doc
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "(*)^13(*)^13(*^13)" ' Combine 3 paragraphs into one
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 \2 \3"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With

End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And this is what the cleaned .docx looks like (with hundreds of records):

```
 12345678900 ABC COMPANY             DEF COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1       123.45 AAABROKER    A0B12345LFD ABC ADDRESS             DEF ADDRESS             XYZ ADDRESS                   BICYCLE PARTS                                           VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 MARKHAM       ON L1L1L1 SHENZHEN         512323                            CN                   
 98765432100 ABC COMPANY             DEF COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1       123.45 AAABROKER    A0B12345LFD ABC ADDRESS             DEF ADDRESS             XYZ ADDRESS                   BICYCLE PARTS                                           VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 MARKHAM       ON L1L1L1 SHENZHEN         512323                            CN
```

Comment: If your code works but it's just slow, it's better suit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ok, I will post there. thanks

Comment: The issue is that you write to Excel many, many times in each iteration of your loop. Suggest you use an array to gather the info in each loop iteration (`Redim Preserve`) to accumulate each bit of info. Then you can write the information in a single pass. Research using arrays with ranges.

Comment: Difficult to make useful suggestions without knowing (eg) how many files your data is split over, or exactly how the data is formatted in Word.  5 days is definitely too long for this process.

Comment: I've added a sample on how the data is formatted in word. In one month, the data is typically split over 100 word documents and each word document can have 500 pages of data in it. SmileyFtW, I will do research into using arrays and ranges. Thank you.

Comment: Is the data actually provided as docx files, or are those converted from some other format?  A plain text version would probably be easier/quicker to extract from.

Comment: data is supplied to us in .docx. I turned off having the msWord window visible (wdApp.Visible = False) and the macro is running a lot faster. by my calculation, doing the same dataset of 220k records would take 14 hours which is way better than 5 days. Would using arrays make it a lot faster?

Comment: If you could share a shortened file (with data redacted as required) people might have other ideas, but it's difficult to test anything without the correct input.

Comment: There's a file attached to the OP's cross-post at: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1302729-how-to-speed-up-vba-macro-to-import-data-from-msword-to-excel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is slow because you are driving Word to analyse your data.  It would be *much* faster to process it as plain text.

The approach I'd take is to convince your data provider to supply it as text files.  If thats not possible, then write a VBA program to convert each Word file to Text.

Once that's done use simple text file handling to read each line from the files, analyse and extract the required data into a variant array, then write the result to Excel.

Note: I haven't included complete code to analyse and extract your data, I'll leave that to you.  Included is a small snippet to get you started.

Something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim t1 As Single, t2 As Single
    Dim DataFile As String
    Dim DataPath As String
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application

    On Error GoTo EH

    'identify sheet to take results
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    t1 = Timer() '<~~ only used to report run time

    ' Create an instance of Word
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application
    WordApp.Visible = False

    ' Set up path to data files
    DataPath = "C:\Data\Temp\SO\" '<~~ update to suit
    SavePath = DataPath & "Txt\" '<~~ optional: save text files to a seperate subfolder

    ' Get first word file in directory
    DataFile = Dir(DataPath & "*.docx")
    Do While DataFile <> vbNullString
        Debug.Print "Convert ", DataFile
        ' Open in word, save as text
        ConvertToText WordApp, DataPath, DataFile, SavePath
        DoEvents

        ' Get next file
        DataFile = Dir
    Loop

    ' Tidy up
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing

    t2 = Timer

    Debug.Print "Convert Time", t2 - t1


    t1 = Timer()
    ' Get first text file in directory
    DataFile = Dir(SavePath & "*.txt")
    rw = 1
    Do While DataFile <> vbNullString
        Debug.Print "Read ", DataFile
        ' process the file
        ReadFile ws, SavePath, DataFile, rw
        DoEvents
        ' Get next file
        DataFile = Dir
    Loop


    t2 = Timer

    Debug.Print "Read Time", t2 - t1

Exit Sub
EH:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Tidy up
    If Not WordApp Is Nothing Then WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub

Sub ConvertToText(WordApp As Word.Application, ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal SavePath As String)
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Long

    ' ensure file is closed if Sub errors
    On Error GoTo EH

    ' Open the file
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FilePath & FileName)

    ' generate Text file name
    i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
    FileName = Left$(FileName, i) & "txt"

    ' Save as text
    WordDoc.SaveAs2 _
        FileName:=SavePath & FileName, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatText, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
        SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, _
        SaveFormsData:=False, _
        SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, _
        Encoding:=1252, _
        InsertLineBreaks:=False, _
        AllowSubstitutions:=False, _
        LineEnding:=0, _
        CompatibilityMode:=0

EH:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Close file
    WordDoc.Close False

End Sub

Sub ReadFile(ws As Worksheet, FilePath As String, FileName As String, ByRef rw)
    'parse text file
    Dim Ln As String
    Dim FileNum As Integer

    Dim ExtractedData() As Variant
    Dim idx As Long

    ' ensure file is closed if Sub errors
    On Error GoTo EH

    ' Text file handling
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open FilePath & FileName For Input As FileNum

    ' Restults array.
    ReDim ExtractedData(1 To 1000000, 1 To 1) ' Excel sheet can hold at most 1048576 rows
    idx = 0
    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
        ' Read a line from file
        Line Input #FileNum, Ln

        ' Add your code to extract required data here
        If Ln Like " [A-Z][A-Z][A-z]########*" Then
            idx = idx + 1
            ExtractedData(idx, 1) = Ln
        End If
        '============================================
    Loop
    ' Place extracted data onto sheet
    ws.Cells(rw, 1).Resize(idx, 1) = ExtractedData
    ' Update row num for next file
    rw = rw + idx

EH:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Clean Up
    Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chris, that code works like a charm. One question, how can I incorporate the find/replace code (to clean the header and footer) to the .docx file prior to saving it as .txt?

Comment: @buroughs I'd need more info on the before and after to answer that

Comment: it's the Sub CleanWordDoc that I posted above. It works if I insert it into a module in Word but I can't figure out how to make it work from Excel.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. It didn't work before because I didn't turn on the Reference to MsWord from Excel. Many thanks for your help. Converting the data only takes seconds now.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Thank you to @chris neilsen and @macropod for their help.

This is the finished code that I used and it is able to process the data in minutes instead of days:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertWordtoExcel()
    Dim t1 As Single, t2 As Single
    Dim DataFile As String
    Dim DataPath As String
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim SavePathFolder As String
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim FD As FileDialog

    On Error GoTo EH

    'identify sheet to take results
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    t1 = Timer() '<~~ only used to report run time

    ' Create an instance of Word
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application
    WordApp.Visible = False

    ' Set up path to data files
    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'Open Folder Picker
    FD.Show
    DataPath = FD.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    Debug.Print "Folder", DataPath
    SavePath = DataPath & "Txt\" '<~~ save text files to a separate subfolder called Txt
    SavePathFolder = Dir(SavePath, vbDirectory) ' If the Txt subfolder does not exist, create it
        If SavePathFolder = vbNullString Then
            VBA.FileSystem.MkDir (SavePath)
        End If

    ' Get first word file in directory
    DataFile = Dir(DataPath & "*.docx")
    Do While DataFile <> vbNullString
        Debug.Print "Convert ", DataFile
        ' Open in word, save as text
        ConvertToText WordApp, DataPath, DataFile, SavePath
        DoEvents

        ' Get next file
        DataFile = Dir
    Loop

    ' Tidy up
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing

    t2 = Timer

    Debug.Print "Convert Time", t2 - t1


    t1 = Timer()
    ' Get first text file in directory
    DataFile = Dir(SavePath & "*.txt")
    rw = 1
    Do While DataFile <> vbNullString
        Debug.Print "Read ", DataFile
        ' process the file
        ReadFile ws, SavePath, DataFile, rw
        DoEvents
        ' Get next file
        DataFile = Dir
    Loop


    t2 = Timer

    Debug.Print "Read Time", t2 - t1

Exit Sub
EH:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Tidy up
    If Not WordApp Is Nothing Then WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub

Sub ConvertToText(WordApp As Word.Application, ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal SavePath As String)
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Long

    ' ensure file is closed if Sub errors
    On Error GoTo EH

    ' Open the file
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FilePath & FileName)

    With WordDoc.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "[ ]{2,}[^13]{1,}(REPORT NUM   :)" 'Clean header on each page
    .Replacement.Text = "\1"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "REPORT NUM   : * CTRY OF ORIGIN^13" 'Clean header on each page
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[ ]{2,}ACTUAL SHP TOTAL*[ ]{20,}^13^m" 'Clean footer on some pages
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[ ]{2,}TOTAL FOR DUTY*[ ]{20,}^13^m" 'Clean more footers
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "REPORT NUM   :*SUMMARY*[\*] [\*][ ]{20,}[^13]{1,}" 'Clean last page
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "^13^m" ' Clean all page breaks
    .Replacement.Text = "^13"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[^13]{2,}" ' Clean empty paragraphs
    .Replacement.Text = "^13"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "(*)^13(*)^13(*)^13" ' Combine 3 paragraphs into one and add file name at the end
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 \2 \3 " + FileName + "^13"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  End With


    ' generate Text file name
    i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
    FileName = Left$(FileName, i) & "txt"

    ' Save as text
    WordDoc.SaveAs2 _
        FileName:=SavePath & FileName, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatText, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
        SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, _
        SaveFormsData:=False, _
        SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, _
        Encoding:=1252, _
        InsertLineBreaks:=False, _
        AllowSubstitutions:=False, _
        LineEnding:=0, _
        CompatibilityMode:=0

EH:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Close file
    WordDoc.Close False

End Sub

Sub ReadFile(ws As Worksheet, FilePath As String, FileName As String, ByRef rw)
    'parse text file
    Dim Ln As String
    Dim FileNum As Integer

    Dim ExtractedData() As Variant
    Dim idx As Long

    ' ensure file is closed if Sub errors
    On Error GoTo EH

    ' Text file handling
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open FilePath & FileName For Input As FileNum

    ' Restults array.
    ReDim ExtractedData(1 To 1000000, 1 To 1) ' Excel sheet can hold at most 1048576 rows
    idx = 0
    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
        ' Read a line from file
        Line Input #FileNum, Ln

        ' Add your code to extract required data here
        'If Ln Like " [A-Z][A-Z][A-z]########*" Then
            If Ln Like " *" Then
            idx = idx + 1
            ExtractedData(idx, 1) = Ln
        End If
        'End If
        '============================================
    Loop
    ' Place extracted data onto sheet
    ws.Cells(rw, 1).Resize(idx, 1) = ExtractedData
    ' Update row num for next file
    rw = rw + idx

EH:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Clean Up
    Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not apparent to me where or how 'CTY/SITE/SORT:' is relevant to what you're doing, as it doesn't appear in the data snippet you've posted. The following Word macro shows how you might go about parsing a document that contains just the data in the data snippet you've posted. As coded, it merely outputs the first such record at the end of the document - the code necessary to generate output for the whole document has been commented out. Comments in the code show how the output is structured. Replacing all vbCr instances except the last with vbTab is all that's required to turn the output for each record into a single line for Excel.

For Excel-driven code to process a whole folder of Word documents, see, for example: https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?8900-Help-with-VBA-to-extract-data-from-Word-to-Excel&p=36586&viewfull=1#post36586. As you will see, there is no need to use Selection - which imposes a significance performance hit.

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim p As Long, StrOut As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "^13[!^13]@^13 <[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{8}"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p^&"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "REPORT NUM * CTRY OF ORIGIN^13"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "^13[ ]@TOTAL FOR DUTY * TOTAL VALUES[!^13]@^13*^13"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[ ]{2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = "^t"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "(^t[A-Z]{2}) ([A-Z0-9]{5,})[ ^t]"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1^t\2^t"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "([0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{2}) "
    .Replacement.Text = "\1^t"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "^13 (<[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{8}) "
    .Replacement.Text = "^p\1^t"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "^13"
    .Replacement.Text = "^l"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[^l]{2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "^l"
    .Replacement.Text = "^t"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  For p = 2 To .Paragraphs.Count - 1
    With .Paragraphs(p).Range
      'StrOut =
      'Shipment ID, Description, Quantity, Weight, Value, Broker, Country of Origin
      'Consignee Name, Consignee Street, Consignee City, Consignee State, Consignee Zip,
      'Importer Name, Importer Street, Importer City, Importer State, Importer Zip,
      'Shipper Name, Shipper Street, Shipper City, Shipper State, Shipper Zip,
      StrOut = StrOut & Split(.Text, vbTab)(8) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(12) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(4) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(5) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(6) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(7) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(24) & vbCr & _
        Split(.Text, vbTab)(1) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(9) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(15) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(16) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(17) & vbCr & _
        Split(.Text, vbTab)(2) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(10) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(18) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(19) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(20) & vbCr & _
        Split(.Text, vbTab)(3) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(11) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(21) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(22) & vbTab & Split(.Text, vbTab)(23) & vbCr
    End With
  Next
  'Instead of .InsertAfter, write StrOut to Excel
  .InsertAfter vbCr & StrOut
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To populate the worksheet you might use something along the lines of:

```
Dim StrRow As String, lRow As Long, r As Long, c As Long
With ActiveSheet
  lRow = .UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
  For r = 0 To UBound(Split(StrOut, vbCr))
    StrRow = Split(StrOut, vbCr)(r)
    For c = 0 To UBound(Split(StrRow, vbTab))
      .Cells(r + lRow, c + 1).Value = Split(StrRow, vbTab)(c)
    Next
  Next
End With
```

Comment: macropod, my apologies. I have updated the data snippet.

Comment: I've updated the code with a few more Find/Replace Ops in Word to take account of your page/data headers & footers.

Comment: That's an interesting code and I see how it can be useful. I'm having a hard time understanding and dissecting the .Text and .Replacement.Text expressions though.  And the code also doesn't go to next page within the .docx file. Would the idea be to eventually convert the trimmed data into a .csv?

Comment: The code uses Word's *wildcard* Find/Replace tools to do the initial parsing. You'll see what it's done in that regard if you look at what's left at the top of the document. Did you have a look at the output the code sends to the end of the document? That's essentially what it'd be outputting to Excel.

Comment: Cross-posted (without even acknowledging the help given here) at: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1302729-how-to-speed-up-vba-macro-to-import-data-from-msword-to-excel.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: macropod, my apologies about the cross posting. I really appreciate what you are doing and the help you have given here.

Comment: Hi macropod, I was able to clean the data on word .docx file using the find & replace method. Thank you for that tip. The data is now separated by tab and ends with a paragraph. My question is, what would be the best way to transfer the data to excel? should I use the Split function?

Comment: The simplest way to output the columns to Excel is to use code such as I've added to the answer above.

Comment: Hi Macropod, I found a new approach but I am not sure if it is practical. Instead of separating the datasets using tabs, I preserved the spaces that were used to separate the data. I then cleaned the header and footer using find&replace and combined the paragraphs so that it is one record per paragraph. I then saved the cleaned .docx as a .txt file and import that into excel. As the data is nicely arranged into columns separated by spaces, I used the Text Import Wizard and choose Fixed Width as the data type. Some manipulation on the positioning and voila.

Comment: But the next problem is applying the same macro to all the .docx files in the folder and eventually merging all the data into one excel. I've updated my original post, I hope you can help. Thank you in advance.